# ServiceHost only supports class service types. wcf

Tags: asp.net, wcf, c#-4.0

i just created one web application. and i using wcf service file. how ever i can not get service reference from this local web service.

here is my screen shot :

[image]

here is my local wcf service file stays as :

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Admin_Staff_Care.SC_WCF.IRestServiceImpl" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/RestServiceImplClient.cs" %>
```

but i unbale to get these methods. with Project > Add Web reference > and i follow step:

[image]

after that i expand service then i show this message like :

```
There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:4870/RestServiceImplClient.svc/$metadata'.
The request failed with the error message:
--
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ServiceHost only supports class service types.</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:pointer; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>ServiceHost only supports class service types.</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

            <br><br>

            <b> Exception Details: </b>System.ArgumentException: ServiceHost only supports class service types.<br><br>

            <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code>

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.                      </code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code><pre>

[ArgumentException: ServiceHost only supports class service types.]
   System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceDescription.GetService(Type serviceType) +13498366
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.CreateDescription(IDictionary`2& implementedContracts) +60
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses) +148
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.InitializeDescription(Type serviceType, UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses) +49
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) +153
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) +34
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +538
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +1489
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +53
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) +666

[ServiceActivationException: The service '/RestServiceImplClient.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: ServiceHost only supports class service types..]
   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +513025
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +182
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult ar) +365683
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar) +165
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +9930149
</pre>                      </code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

            <b>Version Information:</b> Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4250.0

            </font>

    </body>
</html>
<!-- 
[ArgumentException]: ServiceHost only supports class service types.
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceDescription.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.CreateDescription(IDictionary`2& implementedContracts)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.InitializeDescription(Type serviceType, UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
[ServiceActivationException]: The service '/RestServiceImplClient.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: ServiceHost only supports class service types..
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)
-->
--.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:4870/RestServiceImplClient.svc'.
The requested service, 'http://localhost:4870/RestServiceImplClient.svc' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

how i resolve this issue please help me....

**2nd update for WCF Project app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService5.Service1"
               behaviorConfiguration="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  contract="WcfService5.IService1"
                  bindingConfiguration="LargeWeb"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>


    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="LargeWeb" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>


  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

**2nd update for Web Application Web.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://desktop-684ueha:8000/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"/>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 2):

This error is because you entered the wrong debug attribute value in your local wcf service file, the attribute value of debug here should be the implemented service class type, not the service interface.

[image]

Change the IRestServiceImpl in the figure to the service class that implements this interface.

You can first publish the wcf service to iis to test whether the service can be called normally. Then add a service reference to the client.

Comment: i follow your suggestion but still getting error like this: `There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:4870/bin/RestServiceImplClient.svc/$metadata'.
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:4870/bin/RestServiceImplClient.svc'.
There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:4870/bin/RestServiceImplClient.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException,`

Comment: i just use localhost web service but still getting error like :`The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.`

Comment: Can you provide some information about the service configuration and SVC files?

Comment: What is your APP.config file like?

Comment: Your service should be WcfService5.IService1, but the service in your svc file is Admin_Staff_Care.SC_WCF.IRestServiceImpl, I think this may be the problem.